# Why does string.Compare seem to handle accented characters inconsistently?

Tags: c#, sorting, diacritics, string-comparison

If I execute the following statement:

```
string.Compare("mun", "mün", true, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

The result is '-1', indicating that 'mun' has a lower numeric value than 'mün'.

However, if I execute this statement:

```
string.Compare("Muntelier, Schweiz", "München, Deutschland", true, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

I get '1', indicating that 'Muntelier, Schewiz' should go last.

Is this a bug in the comparison? Or, more likely, is there a rule I should be taking into account when sorting strings containing accented

---

The reason this is an issue is, I'm sorting a list and then doing a manual binary filter that's meant to get every string beginning with 'xxx'.

Previously I was using the Linq 'Where' method, but now I have to use this custom function written by another person, because he says it performs better.

But the custom function doesn't seem to take into account whatever 'unicode' rules .NET has. So if I tell it to filter by 'mün', it doesn't find any items, even though there are items in the list beginning with 'mun'.

This seems to be because of the inconsistent ordering of accented characters, depending on what characters go after the accented character.

---

OK, I think I've fixed the problem.

Before the filter, I do a sort based on the first *n* letters of each string, where *n* is the length of the search string.

Comment: It's moments like this that I wish the .NET Framework was open-source, so I could just step through in debug mode and figure out exactly what it's doing.

Comment: @jonathanconway: Stepping through the source code of the base class library is possible, see http://blogs.msdn.com/sburke/archive/2008/01/16/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code.aspx

Comment: @divo Thanks for the reference. Never realized this was possible!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is a tie-breaking algorithm at work, see http://unicode.org/reports/tr10/

> To address the complexities of
>   language-sensitive sorting, a
>   multilevel comparison algorithm is
>   employed. In comparing two words, for
>   example, the most important feature is
>   the base character: such as the
>   difference between an A and a B.
>   Accent differences are typically
>   ignored, if there are any differences
>   in the base letters. Case differences
>   (uppercase versus lowercase), are
>   typically ignored, if there are any
>   differences in the base or accents.
>   Punctuation is variable. In some
>   situations a punctuation character is
>   treated like a base character. In
>   other situations, it should be ignored
>   if there are any base, accent, or case
>   differences. There may also be a
>   final, tie-breaking level, whereby if
>   there are no other differences at all
>   in the string, the (normalized) code
>   point order is used.

So, "Munt..." and "Münc..." are alphabetically different and sort based on the "t" and "c".

Whereas, "mun" and "mün" are alphabetically the same ("u" equivelent to "ü" in lost languages) so the character codes are compared

Answer (score 6):

It looks like the accented character is only being used in a sort of "tie-break" situation - in other words, if the strings are otherwise equal.

Here's some sample code to demonstrate:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Compare("mun", "mün");
        Compare("muna", "münb");
        Compare("munb", "müna");
    }

    static void Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        int result = string.Compare(x, y, true, 
                                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

        Console.WriteLine("{0}; {1}; {2}", x, y, result);
    }
}
```

(I've tried adding a space after the "n" as well, to see if it was done on word boundaries - it isn't.)

Results:

```
mun; mün; -1
muna; münb; -1
munb; müna; 1
```

I suspect this is correct by various complicated Unicode rules - but I don't know enough about them.

As for whether you need to take this into account... I wouldn't expect so. What are you doing that is thrown by this?

Answer (score 4):

As I understand this it is still somewhat consistent. When comparing using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` the umlaut character `ü` is treated like the non-accented character `u`.

As the strings in your first example obviously are not equal the result will not be 0 but -1 (which seems to be a default value). In the second example *Muntelier* goes last because *t* follows *c* in the alphabet.

I couldn't find any clear documentation in MSDN explaining these rules, but I found that

```
string.Compare("mun", "mün", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,  
    CompareOptions.StringSort);
```

and

```
string.Compare("Muntelier, Schweiz", "München, Deutschland", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, CompareOptions.StringSort);
```

gives the desired result.

Anyway, I think you'd be better off to base your sorting on a specific culture such as the current user's culture (if possible).

Comment: `CompareOptions.Ordinal` could also be an option. With this option the strings will be compared based on the Unicode values. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.compareoptions.aspx.