# string partial comparison

Tags: c#, .net, string, comparison

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does string.Compare seem to handle accented characters inconsistently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371813/why-does-string-compare-seem-to-handle-accented-characters-inconsistently)

I have the following code

```
var s1 = "ABzzzzz2";
var s2 = "äbzzzzz1";

var cmp = StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase;

Console.WriteLine(string.Compare(s1, 0, s2, 0, 7, cmp)); //prints -1
Console.WriteLine(string.Compare(s1, 0, s2, 0, 8, cmp)); //prints 1
```

How could it be that part of the first string is less than part of the second, while the whole first string is greater than the whole second one?
I've tested it on x64, .net 2.0, 3.5, 4.0

Comment: It seems to me that the numbers at the end take precedence in defining the order.

Comment: @Jan Same result with `2` replaced with `b`, `1` by `a`.

Comment: You can simplify your sample: `var s1 = "a2";
            var s2 = "ä1";` Btw, the Umlaut matters.

Comment: Perhaps the amount of ignorance is reduced if the strings would be equal otherwise?

Comment: I assume that you can find the answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/1371813/284240

Comment: @TimSchmelter Good find! Key sentence from the accepted answer there: *Accent differences are typically ignored, **if there are any differences in the base letters**.*

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: can you please write an answer so I could accept it?

Comment: IMO, this question is duplicate of Tim's one.

Comment: It's also worth noting that in unicode, there is a difference between any letter with an accent on it, and that same letter with same accent at some other code point.

Answer (score 1):

My theory is that the algorithm first normalizes strings and then does the comparison. According to this "äbzzzzz1" normalized as "abzzzzz1". First comparison in normalized form results equality but returning 0 would be inccorent since the actual strings are not equal. So it reverts to ordinal comparison and results -1.

In the second case, after normalization, it is clear that "abzzzzz2" is greater than "abzzzzz1" so the result is 1.

This approach also explains cases mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1371813/284240) 
For normalization details check [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.normalizationform.aspx)